# Compile AND run c++ from VS Code (macOS)

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, compilation, vscode-tasks

I'm trying out c++ for the first time - using VS Code, as I like that text editor.

I've followed this tutorial to set it up: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac

I have got the following tasks.json file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "Build with Clang",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "clang++",
        "args": [
          "-std=c++17",
          "-stdlib=libc++",
          "helloworld.cpp",
          "-o",
          "helloworld.out",
          "--debug"
        ],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

The compilation works fine and I can run the .out-file from the terminal. But I would like to reduce those 2 steps to 1 (compile AND run). Is that possible?

I've heard of the *Code Runner extension*, but would like to try to set it up in the tasks-file - also to learn a little on how it works.

Anyways - Any hints and suggestions are most welcome! I'll post here if I figure it out on my own!

Comment: I would suggest using Xcode. It's an excellent and free IDE and is the default tool for writing C++ on macOS.  Then you can just do `Cmd-R` to build and run your code.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is configure a launch task in your launch.json and add your build task to the prelaunch tasks. Mine looks like this (I use this on Windows with minGW, but on macOsX it should work the same). This launches your program with your debugger and executes your build task first. You don't need any extensions apart from the Microsoft C++ one to run and even have full debug support with breakpoints, etc.

```
{    
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "Path to your executable",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,               
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "Path to your debugger",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "Name of your Build Task"

        }
    ]
}
```